# How to read files by one in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, queue

There are functions to read files in Tensorflow, but these functions accept queues of filenames.

This implies, that I am obliged to deduce label exactrly when reading file, from the file itself.

Unfortunately, I have a list of tuples in memory, where each tuple consists of filename and label. I.e. labels are not in files, but in memory.

Is it possible to create two synchronized queues somehow or in some other way take data and label from different sources?

**UPDATE**

I wrote something like this, but failed

data = [[os.path.join(corpus_dir, filename), label] for (filename, label) in data]

```
def read_my_file():

    records = tf.train.input_producer(data)
    record = records.dequeue()
    filename = record[0]
    filenames = tf.FIFOQueue(1, tf.string)
    filenames.enqueue(filename)
    label = record[1]
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    key, raw = reader.read(filenames)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(raw)
    return image, label


image, label = read_my_file()

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for i in range(10):
        image1, label1 = sess.run(image, label)
        print(label1)
```

Here `data` is a list of tuples in Python memory, and `filenames` is a queue I organized to feed file reader.

Looks awful and does not work:

```
...test05.py", line 37, in <module>
    image1, label1 = sess.run(image, label)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 769, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 915, in _run
    if feed_dict:
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 525, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

As you see, I use conditionning nowhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using [`tf.WholeFileReader`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/WholeFileReader), you may be able to avoid the problem of synchronizing multiple queues by replacing it with the much simpler [`tf.read_file()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/read_file) op, as follows:

```
def read_my_file():
    records = tf.train.input_producer(data)
    filename, label = records.dequeue()
    raw = tf.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(raw)
    return image, label
```